# Is it possible to send a file object in a request from base64 string without needing to writing it to a file and then read from it?

Tags: python

I have this python method which receives a dict

```
{
  "filename": "image.png",
  "data": <base64 string>
}
```

creates a local file object, writes to it, and then read from it and send it in the request.

Is it possible to create the file object and send it with the request without needing to write it locally?

Below is the method:

```
  def add_attachments(self, issue_key, data):
        # add attachment to issue
        try:
            attachments = data["attachments"]

            credentials = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(settings.JIRA_USERNAME, settings.JIRA_TOKEN)
            headers = {'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'}

            url = settings.JIRA_HOST + "/rest/api/2/issue/%s/attachments" % issue_key
            for attachment in attachments:
                print("Uploading file: " + attachment['filename'])
                filename = "temp/" + attachment['filename']
                # create a file in filepath if not exists
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
                    except OSError as exc:  # Guard against race condition
                        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                            raise
                # write to file
                with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                    data_bytes = attachment['data'].encode('utf-8')
                    decoded_data = base64.decodebytes(data_bytes)
                    file.write(decoded_data)
                    file.close()
                # read the file and send request to jira
                with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                    r = requests.post(url, auth=credentials, files=[('file', file)], headers=headers)
                    file.close()

            shutil.rmtree("temp")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a file-like in memory object, like this:

```
data_bytes = attachment['data'].encode('utf-8')
decoded_data = base64.decodebytes(data_bytes)
file = io.BytesIO(decoded_data)
r = requests.post(url, auth=credentials, files=[('file', file)], headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io) like this:

```
file = io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(data_bytes))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o). You would replace this part:

```
# write to file
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    data_bytes = attachment['data'].encode('utf-8')
    decoded_data = base64.decodebytes(data_bytes)
    file.write(decoded_data)
    file.close()
# read the file and send request to jira
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    r = requests.post(url, auth=credentials, files=[('file', file)], headers=headers)
    file.close()
```

with this:

```
from io import BytesIO

data_bytes = attachment['data'].encode('utf-8')
decoded_data = base64.decodebytes(data_bytes)
file = BytesIO(decoded_data) # create ByteIO object and put the decoded data into it

r = requests.post(url, auth=credentials, files=[('file', file)], 
headers=headers)
```